# Writing command response to an output file in KornShell script

Tags: shell, unix, scripting, ksh

I want to capture the output of the following ./symmir executable in an output file.

The executable first asks a question if I want to proceed. As you can see in the following KornShell (ksh) script, I answer "Y" to the question. I want to specifically capture the response after I answer the question.

```
#!/bin/ksh
./symmir <<EOF
Y
EOF
```

The following will not work as it will just redirect the question to the file1 and not the response after I answer the question.

```
#!/bin/ksh
./symmir >> file1 <<EOF
Y
EOF
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: I suspect `symmir` is a vendor supplied command, and has the option to suppress the confirmation prompt.  It's better to use that mechanism.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If know the number of lines in the answer, you can do something like this:

```
# assumed 1 line in the answer
./symmir <<EOF |tail -n 1 >>file1
Y
EOF
```

Or, if you can make `symmir` to output the question and the answer to different streams - one to stdout and one to stderr, you can redirect only one of them:

```
# assumed symmir writes answer to stderr: echo $answer 1>&2
./symmir <<EOF 2>>file1
Y
EOF
```

Answer (score 0):

Would

```
#!/bin/ksh
./ask_me <<EOF >> file1
Y
EOF
```

work?

However, your code

```
#!/bin/ksh
./ask_me >> file1 <<EOF 
Y
EOF
```

works just fine in my tests as well.

The code to get/print string is (ask_me.c):

```
 #include <stdio.h>

 int main()
 {
   char input[256];
   gets(input); /* Unsafe */

   printf("You have entered '%s'\n", input);

   return 0;
 }
```

Comment: Neither ./ask_me <<EOF >> file1  nor ./ask_me >> file1 <<EOF works for me. Both are redirecting the question to the file1.  Thank you for your help though.

Answer (score 0):

Could this be the EMC symcli symmir command?

If this is the case, use the `-noprompt` option, which prevents the command from asking for confirmation.